# Possible to destroy object using a def?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to delete an object via this simple code:

```py
class test():
    def __del__(self):
        print("deleted!")

def destroy_test(obj):
    del obj
    
t = test()
destroy_test(t)
```

But it doesn't destroy the object `t`.
I can't just use `del` in code, because I need to define it as a custom function for my project.

So how can you delete an object by using a def to do it?

Comment: Why would you call a function when you can use `del` directly ? Anyway, note that you can only delete names, and objects will be removed when no name refers to them anymore. Son no, you can't do that in a function, as you can only delete the name of the parameter that refers to your object locally - and it had other references before.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: mhh, ok. But what if I would do something like this? : class test():
    def __del__(self):
        print("deleted!")

    def destroy_self(self)
        del self

def destroy_test(obj):
    obj.destroy_self()
    
t = test()
destroy_test(t)

Comment: I imagine your *real* problem might be better addressed by the `with` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
class test():
    def __del__(self):
        print("deleted!")

def destroy_test(obj):
    print('inside', locals()) #inside {'obj': <__main__.test object at 0x7fc65c41eeb0>}
    print(obj is globals()['t']) # True
    del obj
    
t = test()
destroy_test(t) # you are deleting 'obj' not 't' so one ref still exists
```

```
globals()['t'] #<__main__.test at 0x7f30f02e8040>
```

```py
class test():
    def __del__(self):
        print("deleted!")

def destroy_test(l):
    print('inside', locals()) #inside {'l': [<__main__.test object at 0x7f0874b10070>]}
    del l[0]
    
t = [test()]
destroy_test(t) # now you have deleted the element
```

```
globals()['t'][0]
```

```
[]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked for me. So if I understand correctly it is storing the name in a list and will del the instance of that class by the name stored in the list?

Comment: I mean this is a quirky way to refer to that variable directly without any aliases in between, It is certainly removing the first element and will be collected by garbage collector subsequently

Answer (score 1):

This answer as posted is also a question:

What output do you get from this code?

```py
class test():
    def __del__(self):
        print("deleted!")

t = test()
t = None
```

and why do you see this output?

Comment: I dont get any output, the only thing that would print is if the __del__ def. would be executed if object t would be destroyed.

Comment: I see `deleted!` printed out. Why don't you see the same thing?

Comment: I dont know, I found a pretty similar code in a different forum, but some say it doesnt work, some say it does work. But from the comment above, it looks like that you can only destroy (delete) objects via its name not via its object id.

Comment: To have any chance of deleting an object, you have to find all the names that refer to it. In this toy example, there is only `t`. I make `t` refer to something else, which means that there is no longer anything referring to that instance of `class test`.